# how to get position from GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridView with 20 images in it.
I want to maintain the list's position when I rotate my device.

I have already tried these methods

```
int index= gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

it returns 0

I have already tried onPause, onResume, onSaveInstanceState(), onRestoreInstanceState  always returns 0

Is there any other option left?
or any idea why I'm having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to all of your activity in the manifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Example:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Jaydip
And tell me what is the difference then between your solution and the code

int index= gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

Comment: Your Welcome @user2983359

Comment: When change orientation at that time activity is refresh so in your code you will always get 0 position and when you set `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` it's not refresh activity so there will not load your gird view again

Comment: Your always Welcome